# Scrolling parent, cursor enters child with inner scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrollable `body`, with scrollable `divs` inside.

When scrolling the `body`, if the cursor enters one of the `divs`, it starts scrolling that instead.

How can I prevent this? Intuitively, I want scrolling to happen only on the element where the action started.

Comment: This is the expected behavior from the browser!

Comment: How would you detect when the user wants to scroll a div? Would they have to scroll all the way to the top/bottom of the body first?

Comment: I think this can be done. I could catch mousewheel events, and scroll the elements myself in the worst case. Is that impossible? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: how would the user know to scroll an element vs another vs the body?  Changing user expectations can bring more headaches (i.e. unusual UX)